# Handle cleanup limited simple webserver loop after response

Tags: .net, f#, httplistener

I wrote a script to get a access token (implicit flow) using F#.
For this I start a simple webserver/listener and only want to handle the redirect followed by sending the token back to the client/listener.

What I am stuck on is a clean/proper way to handle the cancellation and cleanup. The thing is I need to start listening first, then launch the browser for redirect. So I need to wait after launching the browser with a cancel/completion/cleanup mechanism ready.

Overview of the order:

1. Start 'server' with handler/consumer
2. Open browser with auth url
3. Block/wait at call 'getOauthTokenDesktop' until step 5. passes
4. When redirected js fetch token and send to client/script.
5. If received token post token surfaces in consumer method, listener is closed and any other resources released

I have tried using a cancellation token but I need to pass it around everywhere and manage that with the listener status at the handler itself. I am aware of F# mailbox processors and how they could be used to handle httplistener requests, but I feel for just a single up and down request this would be overkill and bring unused features.

This is what I have, for now I am just blocking with WaitOne.

**Update**
It now exits/continues after receiving a token.
I put a cancellation token in the type itself and decided to call stop etc just from a match in the mainloop. I struggled with the async part wher I wanted to return TokenResult but the signaute kept saying it was expecting to be Async of Unit even though no branches were unit or of different type.

```ml
#!/usr/bin/env -S dotnet fsi

open System
open System.IO
open System.Net
open System.Text
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Threading

"""
Acquire OAuth implicit flow token for a desktop clients.
Api used is the Twitch Helix api, the api offers multiple OAuth tokens.
The implicit token flow is suited for non server to server requests and
returns a token of type 'bearer' in the url fragment.
Fragment is sent to the desktop client after redirecting to a local page.
The redirect page will grab the token from the url fragment and post it to the client.
REQUIREMENTS:
- Client-id from developer console (This uses a client-id for application from twitch dev console.)
- Available port on loopback interface (localhost/127.0.0.1), ipv4 used here.
- Template post url should match redirect url, the default html template matches the deafult redirect url.
"""

[<Literal>]
let CLIENTID = "< CLIENT-ID FOR APPLICATIONS FROM DEV CONSOLE >"

[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module OAuthHttp =
    [<Literal>]
    let loopbackRedirect = @"http://localhost:3768/"

    [<Literal>]
    let redirectHtml =
        """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>.NET OAuth2 implicit token as fragment.</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Token here</h1>
        <div id="token"></div>
        </body>
        <script>
            var hashKv = window.location.hash.substring(1).split("&");
            var maybeToken = hashKv[0].split("=");
            var textTag = document.querySelector("#token");
            var result = maybeToken[0] == "access_token" ? maybeToken[1] : "Failed to authenticate";
            textTag.innerHTML = result;
            function sendToken () {
            fetch("http://localhost:3768/tokenGet/", {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ token: result })
            })
            }
            window.onload = sendToken();
        </script>
        </html>
        """

    type OS =
        | OSX
        | Windows
        | Linux
    // Jack Mott - http://fssnip.net/7OP/title/Detect-operating-system
    let getOS =
        match int Environment.OSVersion.Platform with
        | 4
        | 128 -> Linux
        | 6 -> OSX
        | _ -> Windows

    let launchAuthBrowser (apiAuthUrl: string) =
        printfn "Launching with %s" apiAuthUrl
        let os = getOS
        match os with
        | OS.Linux -> Process.Start("xdg-open", apiAuthUrl)
        | OS.OSX -> Process.Start("open", apiAuthUrl)
        | OS.Windows -> 
            // Query seperators won't be included using proces without this workaround.
            let urlForProcess = apiAuthUrl.Replace("&", "^&");
            new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c start %s{urlForProcess}",UseShellExecute = true ,CreateNoWindow = false)
            |> Process.Start

    type TokenResult = { token:string }

    type requestConfig = { redirectUrl:string; redirectPage:string; }

    type Visit =
        | Redirect of string
        | TokenPost of TokenResult
        | Invalid of string

    type OauthServer (redirectUrl: string, redirectPage: string) =
        let serverToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        let handler (serverCtx: requestConfig) =
            let confHandler (ctx: HttpListenerContext) =
                async {
                    match ctx.Request.RawUrl with
                    | "/" ->
                        let page = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverCtx.redirectPage)
                        ctx.Response.ContentType <- "text/html"
                        ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(page, 0, page.Length)
                        ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close()
                        return Redirect ctx.Request.UserHostAddress
                    | "/tokenGet/" -> 
                        use sr = new StreamReader(ctx.Request.InputStream, ctx.Request.ContentEncoding)
                        let msg = sr.ReadToEnd()
                        let result = Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TokenResult>(msg)
                        return TokenPost { token =  result.token }
                    | _ ->
                        return Invalid ctx.Request.RawUrl
                }
            confHandler

        let serverLoop (conf: requestConfig) consumer f = 
            async {
                use listener = new HttpListener()
                listener.Prefixes.Add conf.redirectUrl
                listener.Start()
                
                while listener.IsListening do
                    let! context = Async.FromBeginEnd(listener.BeginGetContext, listener.EndGetContext)
                    printfn "Received request"
                    let! result = f context
                    match result with
                    | TokenPost token -> consumer token; listener.Stop(); serverToken.Cancel(); 
                    | Redirect userHost -> printfn "User visited redirect page from host: %s" userHost
                    | Invalid path -> printfn "Did not recognize the path: %s" path
            }
        member this.startServer(server:requestConfig) consumer =
            printfn "Starting oauth redirect server"
            Async.Start((serverLoop server consumer (handler server)), serverToken.Token)
            serverToken

    let createServer (redirectUrl: string) =
        { redirectUrl=redirectUrl; redirectPage = redirectHtml }

    let startOauthRequest (clientId:string) (consumer: TokenResult -> 'u) (server:requestConfig) =
        let serverHost =
            new OauthServer(server.redirectUrl, server.redirectPage)
        let handle = serverHost.startServer server consumer
        $"https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={server.redirectUrl}&scope="
        |> launchAuthBrowser
        |> ignore
        handle.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne()

let getOauthTokenDesktop clientId =
    // Request implicit token using default localhost ipv4 in OAuthHttp type, clientId can be filled at the top.
    OAuthHttp.createServer OAuthHttp.loopbackRedirect
    |> OAuthHttp.startOauthRequest clientId (fun tokenResult -> printfn "Got the token: %A" tokenResult.token )

getOauthTokenDesktop CLIENTID
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) method in your callback handler to stop the application.

If you do this, then you can register any cleanup you need on the ApplicationStopping event on this type, neatly consolidating it all.

Comment: This is some good info, I never knew about the method. I posted my question more aimed at the control flow of F# async. But the question just wasn't good :p . So I hesitate to mark this as answer, it's really good point though for the general question 'how to cleanup application resources'.